# Switching between date format in a for loop; Python

Tags: python, date, if-statement, for-loop

The date in my data is stored in two different formats:

`Dienstag 31. Dezember 2013` and `30. Juni 2007`

I wrote scripts to extract `Year/Month/Day` from both formats and store them in a list:

```
for row in reader:
    line_count = line_count + 1
    if row[1] == "DATE":
        pass
    else:
        date = row[1].encode('utf-8')
        year = date.split('.')[1].split(" ")[2]
        day = date.split(" ")[0]
        day = day.replace('.', '')
        month = date.split('.')[1].split(' ')[1]
```

for the first format

and

```
date = row[1].encode('utf-8')
year = date.split('.')[1].split(" ")[2]
day = date.split(" ")[0]
day = day.replace('.', '')
month = date.split('.')[1].split(' ')[1]
```

for the second format

However these date formats are randomly occurring throughout the dataset (`row[1]`). Is there a way to tell Python when it encounters one of the formats to use the respective script (like an `if` statement)?
Thanks.

Comment: Is the word Dienstag (or any other day in your language) always expected before the date?

Comment: Any other Weekday in German (Montag, Dienstag, Mittwoch, Donnerstag, Freitag, Samstag, Sonntag)

Comment: Done. Give me 2 minutes to test a couple of cases.

Comment: Well @Zlo do you need These dutch week day names or not?

Comment: Does your second pattern always start with number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the first character in the string is alpha.

```
if date[0].isalpha():
    # call your function for German dates here
else:
    # call the other function
```

Answer (score 2):

If any only if the second pattern starts with a number

```
if (date[0].isdigit()):

      ***method for pattern2***
else:

      ***method for pattern1***
```

Comment: @alexisdevarennes I don't think so we both had only 5 sec difference

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if there's a compulsion on you but Regular Expressions are more suitable for a problem of this kind. The best part is, it is very robust yet flexible -> you can easily make modifications if you expect more formats (maybe American style like January 31, 2004). Five lines of code rather than original 15 ;)

Here's the code:

```
import re

reg_date = "(Montag|Dienstag|Mittwoch|Donnerstag|Freitag|Samstag|Sonntag)*\s*(\d{1,2})\.\s+(\w{3,12})\s(\d{2,4})"

def extract_date(string):
    results = re.search(reg_date, string)
    if results:
        date = results.groups()
        return date[1], date[2], date[3]
```

And to use this, simply write a line like:

```
day,month,year = extract_date("Dienstag 31. Dezember 2013 and ")
print day,month,year
```

or another experiment with the second format

```
day,month,year = extract_date("31. May 2013 ")
print day,month,year
```

[image]

Simple, Elegant, Reusable.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with regex, just to give you more options:

```
import re

if (re.search('^[a-zA-Z]',date):
    #Method for First Format
else:
    #Method for Second Format
```